I want to change the dropdown list of the module to be displayed in layouts
I am not a developer and hence using opencart to create my website. When I edit a Layout, the dropdown list of the content is very limited. I want to include a custom dropdown parameter in this.
On the homepage, I want to display 1 of the category which I have created. When I edit the home layout, in the content dropdown list I see only Category under Category header. I want the list to display the categories created by me in this dropdown list. Example; I have a category called Interests. In the dropdown list under category I want the list to show the name of the category Interest. This will be irrespective the category is Parent or Child. How can I do that.

Please take a look at [ask] and possibly provide us with a [mcve].
